# Gradle failure with 'unknown options: -ios_simulator_version_min -sdk_version' using Xcode 15

Tags: xcode, kotlin, gradle

I have recently upgraded to Xcode 15 and am getting the error `ld: unknown options: -ios_simulator_version_min -sdk_version` when trying to build a framework for X64 targets. As per the issue here [KT-60230](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-60230/Native-unknown-options-iossimulatorversionmin-sdkversion-with-Xcode-15-beta-3) I have tried to add `"-ld64"` to the linkerOpts but I am unsure that I am doing so in the correct way as I still get the same error with the below code.

Here is the relevant part of my 'build.gradle.kts' file, any help would be appreciated:

```
kotlin {

    ...

    var debugFrameworks: List<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.Framework> = listOf()
    var releaseFrameworks: List<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.Framework> = listOf()

    val iosArm32 = iosArm32("iosArm32")
    val iosArm64 = iosArm64("iosArm64")
    val iosX64 = iosX64("iosX64")

    configure(listOf(iosArm32, iosArm64, iosX64)) {
        binaries.framework("MyFrameworkName") {
            baseName = "[MyFrameworkName]"
            embedBitcode("bitcode")
            linkerOpts("-ld64")
        }
        debugFrameworks = debugFrameworks + binaries.getFramework("MyFrameworkName", "Debug")
        releaseFrameworks = releaseFrameworks + binaries.getFramework("MyFrameworkName", "Release")
    }

    val iosArm32Main by sourceSets
    val iosArm64Main by sourceSets
    val iosX64Main by sourceSets

    val iosMain by sourceSets.creating {
        dependsOn(sourceSets.commonMain.get())
        iosArm32Main.dependsOn(this)
        iosArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
        iosX64Main.dependsOn(this)
    }

    val iosArm32Test by sourceSets
    val iosArm64Test by sourceSets
    val iosX64Test by sourceSets

    val iosTest by sourceSets.creating {
        dependsOn(sourceSets.commonTest.get())
        iosArm32Test.dependsOn(this)
        iosArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
        iosX64Test.dependsOn(this)
    }
```

Comment: What's your Kotlin version? It should have been solved with 1.9.10.

Comment: @Krokomot, I am using 1.7.10, I understand it is fixed in 1.9.10 but have some dependencies which make moving to 1.9.10 difficult so I am looking to get an answer which explains why the workaround doesn't work for me

Comment: Better to mention that in your question, otherwise you'll get "upgrade kotlin" answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who is having this issue, I ended up upgrading to Kotlin 1.9.10. I was hoping to avoid doing this as it was a right pain, but I could not get the workaround to work.